# Why does the code tell me Vectorsubscribtion is out of range

Tags: c++

I made a program for a Neuronal net, and everything works great but these lines of code:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < Net.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        //Net is a vector of Layers, Layers are a vector of neurons, and Neurons are a Vector of weights and a double "values", the weights are also doubles
        for (unsigned l = 0; l < Net[i].size(); i++)
        {


            for (unsigned k = 0; k < Net[i][l].weights.size(); k++)
            {
                Net[i + 1][k].value = sigmoid(Net[i + 1][k].value);

                Net[i+1][k].value += Net[i][l].value* Net[i][l].weights[k];


            }

        }

    }
```

execute the error Vector subscribting out of range, and I'm trying my best but I can't find the error

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in the second for loop, 'i' is being incremented in the second for loop declaration and the value of 'i' is exceeding your vector size.

Just replace :

```
for (unsigned l = 0; l < Net[i].size(); i++)
```

with :

```
for (unsigned l = 0; l < Net[i].size(); l++)
```

I believe you have a second mistake in which :

```
Net[i + 1][k]
```

should be replaced in three places (in between the **) with :

```
Net[i + 1][l]



**Net[i + 1][k]**.value = sigmoid(**Net[i + 1][k]**.value);

**Net[i+1][k]**.value += Net[i][l].value* Net[i][l].weights[k];
```

Comment: Even with the above fix `Net[i + 1][k].value` is also going to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have this error

```
for (unsigned l = 0; l < Net[i].size(); i++)
```

should be

```
for (unsigned l = 0; l < Net[i].size(); l++)
```

It's really not a good idea to use a variable called `l`, it's too easy to mistake for either `i` or `1`.

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from "i" since "i" goes from 0 to size - 1

Comment: @marc Sorry but when `i` equals `size() - 1`, then `i + 1` equals `size()`. That is an error because the vaiid indexes for a vector of size `n` are `0` to `n - 1`.

Comment: I formulated my comment incorrectly, "i" never gets to size-1 because "i" is < than size-1 and not <=.

Comment: @marc Yes you are right. Did the code get editted? I thought it said `i < Net.size()` earlier.

Comment: No worries friend.

Comment: @marc It's not a good idea to edit questions like that because it makes things hard to follow when the answers are for a previous version of the code. At the very least you should make it clear that you are editting the question and leave in the previous version of the code.

Comment: The change from i++ to l++ helps but the error is there anyway

Comment: @notdeletedChannelyet Well the next candidate is `k` in `Net[i+1][k].value`. There's absolutely no guarantee from the code posted that `k < Net[i+1].size()`

Comment: @notdeletedChannelyet All you need to do to track this down is use a debugger. Or, if you don't know how to use a debugger then add some code before every vector access that checks if the index is less than the size of the vector, and print an suitable message if it isn't. You'll soon track down the problem.

Comment: @John well, thats my problem, it's not an ordinary error in the console, it's an error message created by the <vector> file, it brings me to a point in <vector> :   #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0
        _STL_VERIFY(
            _Pos < static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst), "vector subscript out of range");
#endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL != 0

Comment: @notdeletedChannelyet Yes, there's lots of debugging code in the vector implementation, but all it's telling you that you have a vector subscript out of range, just use the techniques I described to track it down. There's no reason to doubt that this is anything but a straightforward bug in your code.